# Heroku, Java, Procfile, Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, maven, heroku, procfile

I'm using heroku with maven to run a server. My goal is to have heroku run the java class server.class as a web dyno.

**How would I write a procfile to execute the java program server.class as web?**

My current Procfile

```
web: java -cp $JAVA_OPTS target/classes/v1/a1/server
```

My error.(From heroku logs)

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx350m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Error: Could not find or load main class target.classes.v1.a1.server
State changed from starting to crashed
```

**Possibly useful information**

The procfile

```
web: java -cp $JAVA_OPTS target/classes/v1/a1/*
```

Returns

```
Error: Could not find or load main class target.classes.v1.a1.myOtherClass
```

My original Procfile(Also didn't work)

```
web: java -cp target/classes/:target/dependency/* server
```

- My file structure is a bit different than the example given in the heroku docs so I modified the procfile a bit.

  My dependencies are not inside /target/dependencies.

  My classes are inside target/classes/v1/a1/.

  server.java has a main method and valid constructor method.

  All my dependencies seem to be in order.

  Maven does builds my .java files into .class files in the target directory.

  I'm on unix so quotes and semicolons probably won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `Procfile` should contain:

```
web: java -cp target/classes/:target/dependency/* v1.a1.server
```

This assumes the following:

- Your `server` class is in the file `target/v1/a1/server.class`
- The Java code for your `server` class includes `package v1.a1;`
- Your class name and file name are lowercase.

A few problems I noticed in your earlier attempts included:

- You are passing `$JAVA_OPTS` to the `-cp` options (incorrect)
- You are using `/` instead of `.` in the fully qualified class name (incorrect)
- You are including the `target` dir in the fully qualified class name (incorrect)

The files in the `target/classes/` and `target/dependency/` directory belong on the classpath (i.e. passed to `-cp`) while the last argument to the `java` command should be the fully qualified class name (in the form `package.Class`).

Comment: Thanks For the Help.

Answer (score 5):

The default Procfile for heroku is written for Linux. Where the separator used is ":".

To use the Procfile on Windows machines modify the Procfile as below

```
web: java -cp target/classes/;target/dependency/* com.yourpackage.MainClassName
```